# Efficient Solution for tridiagonal solving with repeated coefficient lines

Tags: linear-algebra

I working to speedup calls to LAPACK dgtsv for a specific case, where the the coefficients lines have 2 blocks of repeated coefficients and 3 distinct lines (first, "border" and last)

#### First line

(c1  u1  0... )

#### N1 identical rows on the diagonal

(l2  d2  u2  0... )
(0   l2  d2  u2  0... )
(0   0   l2  d2  u2  0...)
... Additional lines with l2/d2/u2 on the diagonal

#### One line "Border"

(0   0   0   0   0   ...  l3  d3  u3  0...)

#### N2 identical rows of the diagonal

(0   0   0   0   0   ...  0   l4  d4  u4  0...)
(0   0   0   0   0   0   ...  0   l4  d4  u4  0...)
(0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...  0   l4  c4  u4  0...)
.. Additional lines with l4/c4/u4 on the diagonal
...

#### Final line (line N1+N2+3)

(0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... l5  c5  )

typical values for N1 and N2 are 500 to 1000.

I wonder if there is a specific, faster solution for this form. I can modify the original LAPACK Fortran code, or the C version from clapack

Thanks, Yair